# How to block unknown browsers in .htaccess?

Tags: linux, .htaccess, spam

I wanted to know that How to block unknown browsers in .htaccess? 
there is a variable in htacess called : BrowserMatchNoCase
but I don not know how to work with it

Comment: You should try asking this question on SeverFault, it is off topic for StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}`, e.g. for browsers that not are Opera

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^Opera/[0-9.]+
RewriteRule [your htaccess]
```

[Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) about BrowserMatchNoCase syntax:

`BrowserMatchNoCase regex [!]env-variable[=value] [[!]env-variable[=value]]`